i want to apply internationalization in next
I want to perform internationalization in footer component but whenever I import i18n it is show error like this:

Server Error Error: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window. And I an implementing code for languagedropdown which shows

i18n.changeLanguage() is not a function.

Folder structure is given below  and backend is in  another directory.
# public
└── locale
    ├── en.json
    └── fr.json
src
├── app
│   └── (user)
│       ├── layout.jsx
│       └── page.jsx
├── components
│   └── layout
│       └── _main
│           ├── footer.jsx
│           └── navbar.jsx
├── lib
│   └── providers.js
└── utils
    └── i18n.js

This is my main layout.jsx file
import * as React from 'react';
import Providers from 'src/lib/providers';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
// import i18next from 'i18next';
export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const cookiesList = cookies();
  const hasCookie = cookiesList.get('token');

  return (
    <html lang={'en-US'}>
      <body>
        <Providers isAuth={hasCookie}>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

I want to apply internationalization in this given file.
'use client';
// react
import React from 'react';

// mui
import { alpha } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Typography, Container, Stack, Box, IconButton } from '@mui/material';
// next
import NextLink from 'next/link';
// components
import NewsLetter from './newsletter';

// icons
import { IoLogoInstagram } from 'react-icons/io5';
import { FaFacebook, FaLinkedin } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { IoLogoYoutube } from 'react-icons/io';

const SOCIAL_MEDIA_LINK = [
  {
    name: 'facebook',
    linkPath: 'https://www.facebook.com/techgater',
    icon: <FaFacebook className="facebook" />
  },
  {
    name: 'instagram',
    linkPath: 'https://www.instagram.com/techgater',
    icon: <IoLogoInstagram className="insta" />
  },
  {
    name: 'linkedin',
    linkPath: 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/89683736/admin',
    icon: <FaLinkedin className="linkedin" />`
  },
  {
    name: 'youtube',
    linkPath: 'https://www.youtube.com/@techgaterwebsolutions7394',
    icon: <IoLogoYoutube className="youtube" />
  }
];

export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        // bgcolor: (theme) => alpha(theme.palette.secondary.main, 0.2),
        bgcolor: 'background.paper',
        borderTop: (theme) => `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
        py: 3,

        overflow: 'hidden',
        position: 'relative',
        // '&:before': {
        //   content: "''",
        //   position: 'absolute',
        //   bottom: '-50px',
        //   left: 100,
        //   bgcolor: (theme) => alpha(theme.palette.secondary.light, 0.77),
        //   height: 100,
        //   width: 100,
        //   borderRadius: '50px',
        //   zIndex: 0
        // },
        // '&:after': {
        //   content: "''",
        //   position: 'absolute',
        //   top: 100,
        //   right: '-50px',
        //   bgcolor: (theme) => alpha(theme.palette.secondary.light, 0.77),
        //   height: 100,
        //   width: 100,
        //   borderRadius: '50px',
        //   zIndex: 0
        // },
        display: {
          md: 'block',
          xs: 'none'
        }
      }}
    >
      <Container fixed>
        <Stack
          className="newsletter"
          spacing={1}
          sx={{
            textAlign: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            position: 'relative',
            width: '100%',
            maxWidth: 600,
            margin: 'auto',
            '&:before': {
              content: "''",
              position: 'absolute',
              top: '-80px',
              left: 0,
              ngcolor: (theme) => alpha(theme.palette.secondary.light, 0.77),
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              borderRadius: '50px',
              zIndex: 0
            }
          }}
        >
          <Typography variant="h2" color="text.primary" fontWeight={700}>
            Newsletter
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body1" color="text.secondary">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry
            {`'`}s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
          </Typography>
          <NewsLetter />
          <Stack direction="row" spacing={3} justifyContent="center">
            {SOCIAL_MEDIA_LINK.map((item, index) => (
              <React.Fragment key={index}>
                <IconButton
                  aria-label=""
                  name={name}
                  component={NextLink}
                  href={item.linkPath}
                  target="_blank"
                  sx={{
                    color: (theme) =>
                      index === 0 || index === 2 ? theme.palette.primary.main : theme.palette.error.main,
                    fontSize: 28
                  }}
                >
                  {item.icon}
                </IconButton>
              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
          </Stack>
          <Typography variant="body1" color="text.primary" textAlign="center">
            © 2023 Commercehope. All rights reserved
          </Typography>
        </Stack>
      </Container>
    </Box>
  );
}

This is en.json:
{
    "newsletter": "Newsletter",
    "newsletterDescription": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.",
    "allRightsReserved": "© 2023 Commercehope. All rights reserved"
  }

This is provider file
'use client';
import { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
// redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxStore, persistor } from 'src/lib/redux';
// react
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';
// components
import ThemeRegistry from 'src/theme';
import GlobalStyles from 'src/theme/globalStyles';
import { LinearProgress, Stack } from '@mui/material';
import AuthProvider from './auth';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const ProgressBar = dynamic(() => import('src/components/ProgressBar'), {
  ssr: false
});

export default function Providers(props) {
  const [queryClient] = useState(
    () =>
      new QueryClient({
        defaultOptions: {
          queries: {
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false // default: true
          }
        }
      })
  );

  return (
    <Provider store={reduxStore}>
      <AuthProvider isAuth={props.isAuth}>
        <ThemeRegistry>
          <GlobalStyles />
          <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <Toaster position={'top-center'} />
            <PersistGate
              loading={
                <Stack
                  sx={{
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 'calc(50vh - 2px)',
                    width: '300px',
                    left: 'calc(50vw - 150px)',
                    zIndex: 11
                  }}
                >
                  <LinearProgress />
                </Stack>
              }
              persistor={persistor}
            >
              {props.children}
            </PersistGate>
          </QueryClientProvider>
          <ProgressBar />
        </ThemeRegistry>
      </AuthProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}

Providers.propTypes = {
  isAuth: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

This is i18n.jsx file:
// src/utils/i18n.js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

i18n
  .use(HttpApi)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    },
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/locale/{{lng}}.json' // Correct path for your JSON files
    },
    detection: {
      order: ['queryString', 'cookie'],
      caches: ['cookie']
    }
  });

export default i18n;


Could you edit the question. Tittle is too long, and weird to read, also it lack a lot of useful text. on what you want to do. And your question miss important tags, e.g. the language you are using, so most of us will not read your question because it has not the tags they follow (but do not do a tag spam) -- if you want help, you should help us, else we pass to the next question. -- Please format better your question, I'll not try to parse all things: i have better things to do.

No more data. Edit the question. Remove unnecessary items. Looking at a repository will not make more people help you. Please: edit and format better the question and the tags.

hello @GiacomoCatenazzi can you please review the code

I cannot find a reason. From the error, it seems that a variable is called as a function (and possibly from a return value of an other function). On your code I see no red flags, so maybe it is just incompatibilities between versions. Or try to bisect, until you find the real line which cause the problem.
